# Hetzner sendmail problem "return to sender: User unknown"

Tags: sendmail, mail-transport-agent

for some reason my sendmail is not able to send mails from my virtual server at Hetzner via sendmail.

In my `/etc/mail/aliases` config look like:

```
mailer-daemon: postmaster
postmaster: root
nobody: root
hostmaster: root
usenet: root
news: root
webmaster: root
www: root
ftp: root
abuse: root
noc: root
security: root
fail2ban: root
root: hetzner
```

**It seems be ok because it tries to send the mail then, but log shows:**

```
Aug  9 10:11:47 mydomain sm-mta[16537]: u798BllJ016535: to=<fail2ban@mydomain>, delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=123469, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Aug  9 10:11:47 mydomain sm-mta[16537]: u798BllJ016535: to=hetzner, ctladdr=root (8/0), delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=123469, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Aug  9 10:11:47 mydomain sm-mta[16537]: u798BllJ016535: u798BllJ016537: postmaster notify: User unknown
Aug  9 10:11:48 mydomain sm-mta[16537]: u798BllJ016537: to=hetzner, ctladdr=root (8/0), delay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=0, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Aug  9 10:11:48 mydomain sm-mta[16537]: u798BllJ016537: to=hetzner, ctladdr=root (8/0), delay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=0, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Aug  9 10:11:48 mydomain sm-mta[16537]: u798BllJ016537: u798BllK016537: return to sender: User unknown
Aug  9 10:11:48 mydomain sm-mta[16537]: u798BllK016537: to=hetzner, ctladdr=root (8/0), delay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=0, dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Aug  9 10:11:48 mydomain sm-mta[16537]: u798BllJ016537: Saved message in /var/lib/sendmail/dead.letter
```

(I hide my domain name in the logfile. but it's configured in `/etc/mail/local-host-names` and `/etc/hosts`)

Comment: Have you run `newaliases` after adding `fail2ban` to your `/etc/aliases` file?

Comment: actually not directly, but i tried to configure sendmail with sendmailconfig. as far as i know this gets invoked then.

Comment: i trashed sendmail and switched to postfix. work there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sendmail sends message to local user/mailbox named `hetzner`.
Your sendmail reports the OS account does not exist.

You may define alias to non local email address e.g.

```
# forward message to local account/mailbox named "archive" and to non local email
hetzner: archive,john.doe@example.net
# sendmail specific hack to deliver to local account and send a copy
user: \user,jane.doe@example.org
```

[see "man aliases"](http://linux.die.net/man/5/aliases.sendmail)

Comment: If you need extra information from the OP, please use the comments below the original post.

Comment: i thought that my VM provider (hetzner) configured that so that it will work. The local account hetzner doe not exists and i want that my server send mail that goes to root goes to my private address. can i configure it like root: myprivate@adress?